# CkEditor removing "text/css" content from "style" tag

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor, config, strip

I need some help with the CkEditor v4.5.7. When I try to manually add some source code with the elements I'll show below, the editor strips the `/css` text from the `text/css` line, when I switch from the source area, to the normal editor area.

Before

[image]

I'll post the "After" without the "<>" characters, cause the forum just let me post 2 links:

---

> style type="text">a:link {   color: red; }
>
> a:visited {   color: green; }
>
> /style

---

checking some other info here on the forum, I saw people saying that most of these problems are solved by adding the `config.allowedContent = true;` parameter to the config.js element, but in my case it didn't work. Below is my config.js, please check it and see if I'm doing something wrong.

Config.js

[image]

Hope you can help me. Thanks already and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You have CKEDITOR.editorConfig defined twice in your config file. It might be ignoring one of them.

Comment: I tried removing the first one, the one without the configurations, but the problem is still there. Thanks for the reply anyway!

Comment: This might just be a pixelated screenshot issue, but it also looks like the line before `config.allowedContent = true;` says "faLse" (with a capital L). Another option is to try the `config.fullPage = true;` option. After making changes to your config file, be sure to do a force refresh (Ctrl+F5) so you aren't loading from cache.

Comment: Its probabily just the screenshot, even I looking again thought it was a capital L haha. But I checked the code and its correct. Also tried the parameter you sugested, but it just added html tags as default on my source code editor. The problem still remains, but I'm trying to figure it out! Thanks again @Rick, you're helping a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have some problem with your configuration file, or perhaps you are not working the the latest files of version 4.5.7.

You can check this example:
https://jsfiddle.net/j0nktq82/
(The files there loaded version 4.5.7 of CKEditor from the CDN).

You can click on the <kbd>Source</kbd> button a few times and see that nothing changed and the output is:

```
<style type="text/css">a:link { color: red;}
    a:visited { color: green;}
</style>
<p><a href="#">Link Example</a><br />
<a href="https://www.google.com/">Link Example</a></p>
```

If you are able to provide a link that demonstrates the problem it might help determine how to solve it.

Comment: thanks for your help. But maybe I'm gonna need to look at this problem from another perspective. I copied the editor from the server and executed it from a "test.html" page I've created and it worked! But if I do the same on the server, execute it on a test page, i get the error again. I'm starting to think that it may be and IIS issue. It may be blocking scripts from that page or something like it, cause the exactly same config worked locally and online didn't.